# MYSQL foreach Row Echo Data

Tags: php, mysql

How do I echo out every column's data of a row from MYSQL results?

I do not know what the rows are as the query is dynamically created.

Here's what I have:

```
$query = $_POST['query'];
// Create connection
$con=mysqli_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name);

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
  echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {

}
```

Comment: Holy SQL injection nightmare, Batman.

Comment: This isn't about protecting against mysql injection but thanks.

Comment: @JohnConde Nobody mentions Robin anymore.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Too many were killed by the Joker. People are afraid to get attached.

Comment: @JohnConde That's why I was always attached to "The Riddler". (grin)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$row` is just an array. Like any other array you can do fun things like iterate over it:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results)) {
    foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo 'Key: ' . $key . ', Value: ' . $value;
    }
    echo  "<br><br>\n"
}
```

Comment: How come it looks like this? `Key: 122, Value: <br>
Key: completedDate, Value: <br>
Key: 123, Value: <br>
Key: amount, Value: <br>
Key: 124, Value: <br>
Key: isPayingOnline, Value: <br>
Key: 125, Value: <br>
Key: isCompleted, Value: <br>` I would like one row of data on one line. Could you format it like that so I can understand what I'm looking at better?

Comment: Change `mysqli_fetch_array` to `mysqli_fetch_assoc`.

Comment: Nicolas, every row is iterated in the while loop. The columns are iterated by foreach loop. You can easly change the output knowing this.

Comment: I have this now, `while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) {
 foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo 'Key: ' . $key . ', Value: ' . $value . "<br>\n";
    }
}` but no data prints out.

Comment: It is because you use mysql_... instead mysqli_... Use the code as in the answer

Comment: Wait a minute, OP isn't querying. All there is, is `$results = mysqli_query($con, $query);` and no `SELECT ...` or am I too fast on the draw?

Comment: They get their query from their form POST: `$query = $_POST['query'];
`

Comment: I am now using this: `while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($results)) {
 foreach ($row as $key => $value) {
        echo 'Key: ' . $key . ', Value: ' . $value;
    }
}` and get an output like this: `Key: applicationId, Value: 1Key: givenName, Value: JimKey: middleName, Value: DanglingKey: familyName, Value: DangleKey: suffix, Value: ESQ.Key: alternativeName, Value: Seymour ButtsKey: gender, Value: M`

Comment: It is, if I want to seperate per row, where would my seperator go? Like a echo '-----';?

Comment: Replace the `"<br>\n"` with whatever you want to go after each row.

Comment: I guess I'm confused why this is happening: `Key: applicationId, Value: 1<br><br>
Key: givenName, Value: Jim<br><br>
Key: middleName, Value: Dangling<br><br>
Key: familyName, Value: Dangle<br><br>
Key: suffix, Value: ESQ.<br><br>` I want all this information to be on one line because this is all information from one row... and there is more too