# How do i get good result useing foreach in row result output

Tags: php, foreach, row

In mysqli database i have mobi2, mobi7,run2,run3 as item_name with book 1905515 for all
example

id   |     book    |   item_name

1    |  1905515  |  mobi2
2    |  1905515  |  mobi7
3    |  1905515  |  run2
4    |  1905515  |  run3

my problem is how do i get each item_name in one loop useing foreach statement i have tried:

```
require("init.php");
$result = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT item_name FROM books WHERE book = 1905515");
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{

  foreach($row as $each);

  $display=$each["item_name"];     echo ', '$display;

 }
```

i get m,m,r,r as result instead of mobi2,mobi7,run2,run3 thanks your time and impact in my solutions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MYSQL foreach Row Echo Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24270793/mysql-foreach-row-echo-data)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You alredy do `foreach` inside `while` and use mysqli_fetch_assoc for correct keys:

```
    require("init.php");
    $result=mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT `item_name` FROM `books` WHERE `book`='1905515'");
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)){
         $display=$row["item_name"];
         echo ', '$display;
    }
```